# how to configure build in html snippets in vscode/intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense, code-snippets

when I type html tag name in VS Code the IntelliSense suggests code snippet. For example if I type "form" snippet generates:

```
<form action=""></form>
```

How can I configure this snippet (I'd like to get rid of "action" attribute)?
Which component is responsible for those snippets? Is it Emmet?

Thanks.

Comment: read this it will help you 
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is Emmet.

Generic snippets are defined in /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions/html-language-features/server/node_modules/vscode-emmet-helper/out/expand/expand-full.js

Simply change:

```
"form": "form[action]",
```

to snippet of your choice, for example:

```
"form": "form[\[formGroup\]]",
```

#### Another approach:

- create directory for your private emmet snippets e.g: ~/.config/emmet
- open VS Code settings (Ctrl + ,)
- search for emmet.extensionPath and set it to ~/.config/emmet
- create ~/.config/emmet/snippets.json file with

> ```
> {
>     "html": {
>         "snippets": {
>             "form": "ju-hu"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

more details https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-custom-emmet-snippets